# Changing the magic tags in same cell - Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am working on Azure Databricks and have fetched a Spark data frame, and need to convert it to R data.frame. I am getting a syntax error when I am using as.data.frame in the same cell for the same.

When tried in different cells, after the initiation of magic tag (%r), and using the same command- it is throwing different errors that object is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the Spark DataFrame as a TempView using [createOrReplaceTempView](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView.html)

##### Registering a Temp View

```
sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView('TempView')
```

Once you have done this, `TempView` would be accessible throughout your Notebook.

Further using `%r` you can create a DataFrame out of it

##### SparkR

```
%r

library(SparkR)

sparkR <- sql('select * from TempView')
```

##### R DataFrame

```
%r

library(SparkR)

sparkR <- collect(sql('select * from TempView'))
```